# Blazor .net 8: Interactivity in navigational components outside Body

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0

I am currently trying to bring a Blazor Server app over to the new Blazor Web App model introduced in .net 8. My main layout looked like this:

```html
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>MyTitle</PageTitle>

<RadzenLayout>
    <MyHeader SidebarToggle="(() => _sidebarExpanded = !_sidebarExpanded)" />
    <MySidebar @bind-IsExpanded="_sidebarExpanded" />
    <RadzenBody class="rz-p-1 rz-pt-3">@Body</RadzenBody>
</RadzenLayout>

<RadzenDialog />
<RadzenNotification />
<RadzenContextMenu />
<RadzenTooltip />

@code {

    private bool _sidebarExpanded = true;
}
```

This worked in Blazor Server, but doesn't work now. The event callbacks never fire.

Even if I replace the layour with a simple button the CLick event never fires.

Is there anything new to it to add interactivity to the navigational components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the *rendermode* for the component. [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#apply-a-render-mode-to-a-component-definition)

First the services must be configured for the respective render mode in `program.cs`

```swift
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode();
```

Then the render mode can be set on the component definition.

#### RC1

```swift
@rendermode RenderMode.InteractiveServer
```

#### RC2

```swift
@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveServer]
```

Or on the component instance,

```html
<MyComponent @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />
```

---

#### Global declaration

From .NET 8 RC2. You can set a global rendermode so that you only declare it on one place as the other components will inherit the rendermode. [Update Blog Post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-rc-2/#blazor)

Comment: I forgot to specify `@attribute [RenderModeInteractiveServer]` on the components. Adding this made it work.