Blazor form submit button doesn't call my submit method
I wrote a login form in Blazor (with some MudBlazor elements) and now I've run the app but after filling in the form and pressing the Submit button nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?
<EditForm Style="width: 700px;" Model="@_loginModel" OnValidSubmit="OnValidLoginSubmit" FormName="LoginForm">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <MudGrid Style="width: 100%;">
        <MudItem Style="width: 100%;">
            <MudPaper Width="100%">
                <MudCardContent>
                    <MudTextField Label="Username or email" HelperText="Type either your username or email" @bind-Value="_loginModel.UsernameOrEmail" For="@(() => _loginModel.UsernameOrEmail)" ErrorText="@_loginUsernameErrorText" OnBlur="OnBlurCallback" />
                    <MudTextField Label="Password" HelperText="Type your password" Class="mt-3" @bind-Value="_loginModel.Password" For="@(() => _loginModel.Password)" InputType="InputType.Password" />
                </MudCardContent>

                @if (_backendLoginResponse is not null)
                {
                    <MudAlert Severity="Severity.Error">@_backendLoginResponse</MudAlert>
                }

                <MudCardActions>
                    <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ml-auto">Login</MudButton>
                </MudCardActions>
            </MudPaper>
        </MudItem>
    </MudGrid>
</EditForm>


Are you using .net 8 with a @rendermode added?

It is .NET8. I'm not sure about the @rendermode (how can I check it?).

Blazor in .NET-8 requires @rendermodes for interactivity. There's many answers out there already for this here's one I posted https://stackoverflow.com/a/77353168/11779494 . Basically for interactivity you need to declare it otherwise your components are static.

Ok, I added @rendermode InteractiveServer at the top of the login page but it's still not working. Anything else I need to change?

Have you registered the services in program.cs? Do you have the relevant packages. You need to do some research.  The form is not the problem.

Look at MudBlazor's templates and see what you're missing. https://github.com/mudblazor/Templates

Please Use below code in App.razor file
<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

I get this error: InvalidOperationException: A component of type 'MyApp.Front.Client.Routes' has render mode 'InteractiveServerRenderMode', but the required endpoints are not mapped on the server. When calling 'MapRazorComponents', add a call to 'AddInteractiveServerRenderMode'. For example, 'builder.MapRazorComponents<...>.AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()'
